# Issue with Spark-scala Join . Looking for a better Approach

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 DF,s like below.

```
+---+---+---+
|  M| c2| c3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+
|  M| c2| c3|
+---+---+---+
|  1| 20| 30|
|  2| 30| 40|
+---+---+---+
```

What should be the best approach to get a new dataframe like below.This means, the new Df has column names c2 and c3 but value is `concat( df1("c1"),df1("c2") )` but with same column name.I can do this with
`df3.withColumn("c2_new",concat( df1("c2"),df2("c2") ))` and then renaming the new column to C2. But ssue is that I have 150+ Columns in my DF.What should be the best approach here?

```
+---+------+-----+
|  M| c2  |   c3 |
+---+-----+------+
|  1| 2_20|  3_30|
|  2| 3_30|  4_40|
+---+------+-----+
```

Comment: Would this be convenient : c2 = 20_2 instead of 2_20

Comment: Unfortunately, that shouldn't be Okay. C1 of the DF1 has to be concatenated with C1 of df2

Comment: yes sure, I'm just asking if it matters to have 20_2 as a result for (M=1, c2) instead of 2_20 (if they should be sorted for instance ?)

Comment: Value of  (M=1, c2) canbe high or low which means sort logic cant be applied, i beleive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a join:

```
val selectExpr = df1.columns.filterNot(_=="M").map(c => concat_ws("_",df1(c),df2(c)).as(c))

df1.join(df2,"M")
  .select((col("M") +: selectExpr):_*)
  .show()
```

gives:

```
---+----+----+
|  M|  c2|  c3|
+---+----+----+
|  1|2_20|3_30|
|  2|3_30|4_40|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: This one is simple and elegant. This will obviously guarantee - C1 of the DF1 will be concatenated with C1 of df2 and not the other way around, I believe. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

If you have a wide columns, you could iterate over columns and apply the same transformations for it. In your case you should merge dataframes and aggregate columns like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType

val commonColumns = (df1.columns.toSet & df2.columns.toSet).filter(_ != "M").toSeq
commonColumns

df1.union(df2)
    .groupBy("M")
    .agg(count(lit(1)) as "cnt", 
        commonColumns.map(c => concat_ws("_", collect_set(col(c).cast(StringType))) as c):_*)
    .select("M", commonColumns:_*)
        .show
```

Here is the output:

```
+---+----+----+
|  M|  c2|  c3|
+---+----+----+
|  1|20_2|3_30|
|  2|3_30|40_4|
+---+----+----+
```

If you have requirement on ordering (i.e. value from `df1` must be on the left side, value from `df2` must by on the right) you could use this trick:

1. Add dateframe number (`1` and `2`) before `union` as a new column
2. Create structure from dataframe number and column value
3. During aggregation take `min` and `max` of this structure
4. Extract the value from the structure
5. Concat values with an underscore

Code:

```
df1
    .withColumn("src", lit(1))
    .union(df2.withColumn("src", lit(2)))
    .groupBy("M")
    .agg(count(lit(1)) as "cnt", 
        commonColumns.map(c => concat(
            min(struct($"src", col(c)))(c),
            lit("_"),
            max(struct($"src", col(c)))(c)) as c):_*)
    .select("M", commonColumns:_*)
    .show
```

The final result is ordered:

```
+---+----+----+
|  M|  c2|  c3|
+---+----+----+
|  1|2_20|3_30|
|  2|3_30|4_40|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Can we guarantee this - C1 of the DF1 will be concatenated with C1 of df2 and not the other way around.

Comment: a bit too complex for my taste